# Sampling distributions of the same proporion but different n

Tags: self-study, sampling, proportion

This is a textbook question of which I don't understand why B should be the correct answer:

> 52% of the population in country X are men.John draws a sample of 50
> persons from this population and counts the amount of men in the
> sample. Steve takes a sample of 200 persons from this population and
> also counts the amount of men. Steve draws a sketch to show John what
> difference between both sampling distributions should be expected.
> Which sketch could be used for this?

[image]

To my knowledge both sampling distributions should be distributed around the same center, namely the 52% proportion. Only will Steve have a better chance of finding a sample proportion closer to the population proportion. This would lead me to answer A, however, according to the book it should be answer B. It could have something to do with the fact that there are more men in the population, so less accurate samples have a higher probability of picking more men than less men, and thus ending up with higher proportions. But then still the difference in sketch B seems very large.

Comment: re "same center": How many men do you expect in the 50-person sample?  How many in the 200-person sample?  Should those expectations be equal?

Comment: If it is any consolation to the OP I misunderstood the question too until I read @whuber comment.